# Images in resource project are not loading inside nested controls

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, runtime, embedded-resource

I've removed some code for brevity, but my problem is that images are not loading from resource project at runtime in included controls. The xaml is in a different project than the images, but both are in the same solution and the xaml project has the resource project as a reference.

The image loads from `Source="/ThinkVisual.Resources;component/Images/save.png"/` but inside `<my:OwnerDetails x:Name="controlOwnerDetails" />` there is an image which does not load.

```
<Button x:Name="btnAddOwnerDetails" ToolTip="Add Owner/Management details" Click="btnAddOwnerDetails_Click">
    <Image Width="16" Height="16" Source="/ThinkVisual.Resources;component/Images/add_button.png" />
</Button>
```

Both the parent and the child controls are in the same project and folder.

```
<lc:LayoutGroup x:Name="layoutCompanyDetails" Header="Company Details" View="GroupBox" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Orientation="Vertical"                     <lc:LayoutGroup x:Name="tabCompanyDetails" View="Tabs" SelectedTabChildChanged="tabCompanyDetails_SelectedTabChildChanged">
                    <lc:LayoutGroup Header="Details">
                        <my:CompanyDetails x:Name="controlCompanyDetails" />
                    </lc:LayoutGroup>
                    <lc:LayoutGroup Header="Owner/Management Details">
                        <my:OwnerDetails x:Name="controlOwnerDetails" />
                    </lc:LayoutGroup>                    
                </lc:LayoutGroup>
                <lc:LayoutItem>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                        <Button x:Name="btnUpdate" ToolTip="Update company details" Padding="0" Margin="0" Width="65" MouseEnter="Button_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="Button_MouseLeave" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=AllPropertiesValid}" Click="btnUpdate_Click">
                            <Button.Content>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Image Width="16" Height="16" Source="/ThinkVisual.Resources;component/Images/save.png"/>
                                    <Label x:Name="lblSaveButton" Padding="2">Update</Label>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Button.Content>
                        </Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                </lc:LayoutItem>
```

The images are visible in Visual Studio but not displayed during execution, project builds and runs without error.

Comment: is the property Copy to Output Directory is set to Copy always? and Build Action to Compile(default)?

Comment: XAML is in ThinkVisual.Administration project and images are in ThinkVisual.Resources project.

The build action of each image is set to resource, and its set to copy always.
The same image is displayed in the parent control, but not in the child control.

Comment: If the `Build Action` of an image file is set to `Resource`, it will be added to the output assembly. Then it is not necessary to copy it to the output directory. Hence, `Copy to Output Directory` should be set to `Do not copy`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the wrong [Pack URI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Make sure your Image in your custom control library is set to `Resource` Build Action and `False` for Copy to Output Directory.

Then change your `Image.Source` to:

```
<Image Width="16" 
       Height="16" 
       Source="pack//application:,,,/ThinkVisual.Resources;component/Images/add_button.png" />
```

Personally, I would put all the images used in XAML in the same project as the XAML to break the dependency.  Image if someone took your assembly and wanted to reuse it.  They would need to create a new project with the same naming convention and file names in order to use the assembly with it's intention.

If the image is used in both assemblies (projects), add the images to each assembly and use proper Pack Uri's.

So if you're using the image in a control defined in `ThinkVisual.Administration` then use

```
Source="pack//application:,,,/ThinkVisual.Adminstration;component/Images/add_button.png"
```

and if the control you're using in `ThinkVisual.Resources` uses the same image, then use the first snippet for `Source`.